# Saving picture croped from div-tag

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, crop

I have found a way to move a picture round in a box made of a  tag. 
It works perfectly as i want it.  The code is as flows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery("#my-image").css({top: 0, left: 0});

        var maskWidth = jQuery("#my-mask").width();
        var maskHeight = jQuery("#my-mask").height();
        var imgPos = jQuery("#my-image").offset();
        var imgWidth = jQuery("#my-image").width();
        var imgHeight = jQuery("#my-image").height();

        var x1 = (imgPos.left + maskWidth) - imgWidth;
        var y1 = (imgPos.top + maskHeight) - imgHeight;
        var x2 = imgPos.left;
        var y2 = imgPos.top;

   jQuery("#my-image").draggable({containment: [x1, y1, x2, y2]});
        jQuery("#my-image").css({cursor: 'move'});
   });

</script>


<div id="my-mask" style="width: 600px; height: 200px; overflow: hidden;">
    <img id="my-image" src="stormP.jpg" width="" height=""/>
</div>
```

Now I want a button that can save the visible part of the picture in a new file.
Can anyone point me in the right direction. I have no clue of how to do that. I'm using PHP, CSS and JQuery.

Alternately I can use CSS to place the hole picture inside the  tag with overflow hidden. 
In that case I need the coordinates of the upper left corner compared to the picture coordinates. Then I would set the background-position: -300px -330px; as the upper left corners X,Y coordinates relative to the picture like this:

```
<div style="cursor: pointer; width: 600px; height: 200px; background-image: url(stormP.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat;  background-position: -300px -330px;">
```

Any of the two will do.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two ways that you can handle this. In `PHP` you can do server side editing (You would pass the coordinates to the server and then use something similar to [GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) in order to crop the image to the set width/height you want), or use the javascript canvas method, which are explained in many tutorials, one of which can be found [here](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-image-crop/).

Comment: That is exactly what I want! My problem is just how to find the starting point of where to crop the picture. 

If I use the div-tag method I would have to start where the top left corner (0,0) of the div-tag is in the picture.

How do I read the coordinates of the picture?

Comment: Can you edit [this jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y6ue1zq1/) a bit to give me an example of what you're trying to accomplish, and I'll help you out further.

Comment: Try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/boskbh/wv6wmu9p/ 

You should be able to drag the picture round in the box (made out of css styled <div> tag).


Correct me if i'm wrong. But if I want to crop the picture to what I se in the box I have to know where the 0,0 coordinate of the div-tag is in the picture. Afterwords I can use that as a starting point for cropping the picture. Right?